# How do I log all UNIX shell commands submitted by all users?

Tags: unix, shell, logging

Is there an elegant way to log every command submitted in all shells on a machine? This is in the context of an infrequently-used Ubuntu server, of which I am the only human user. (There are several user accounts used by automated systems.)

I would like this to be unobtrusive and low-overhead, so I'd love it if there were a simple method involving something like `script`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the dawn of time (actually dating back from the time when people had to actually pay real money per computer cycle they used) Unix and it's clones has had a system called Process Accounting (`acct`) built in.  This allowed the system administrators to know exactly what their users were doing and so could bill them accordingly.

The `acct` facilities still exist in most Unix and Linux systems to this day.

This site: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html tells you how to enable it.

Comment: Can this also be used to log which user performs sudo and su, and which of root's commands afterwards?

Comment: I believe it logs __every__ command run, keyed by user, tty, etc.  You can match up the commands on a tty with the user that was logged in to that tty to trace what users they su'd or sudo'd through.

Comment: Thank you, I was totally unaware of this feature. A quick read of the man pages suggests that logging continues until a low-disk-space condition is reached - hence perhaps a need for a logrotate script.

Comment: i thought process accounting just logged which program ran, not the command with all its arguments  ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy).

It is very simple to install and to remove (no kernel module or patching required). Note that this is not a proper auditing solution and it can easily be circumvented.

Disclosure: I am current snoopy maintainer.

Comment: Bostjan Skufca has also provided additional instructions for installing snoopy in Ubuntu [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server/546155#comment748349_546155) and also in an additional comment in the same thread [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server/546155#comment748352_546155).

Comment: +1 for snoopy; it provides a nice log of command and arguments in /var/log/auth.log

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very nice and quick [way to log all shell commands](http://linuxinmybox.blogspot.com/2012/01/logging-shell-commands-in-linux.html):

> #### Step 1:
>
> Use your favourite text editor to open /etc/bashrc and append the following line at the end:
>
> ```
> export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
> ```
>
> #### Step 2:
>
> Set the syslogger to trap local6 to a log file by adding this line in the /etc/syslog.conf file:
>
> ```
> local6.*                /var/log/cmdlog.log
> ```

[[See the Complete Blog Post Here]](http://blog.kxr.me/2012/01/logging-shell-commands-in-linux.html)

Comment: I alert user would be able to disable this be resetting the variable and because it is executed *"prior to issuing each primary prompt"* this fact would not be logged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sudosh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudosh2/) as a shell wrapper. It includes automatic logging of everything you do, and can play back the log files. [See its website for more information](http://www.shortcutsolutions.net/sudosh2-shell-auditing-software/90-ways-to-use-sudosh2.html).